# ASP.NET build path for release builds

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET website that is causing me a bit of a headache!

I've got `node` installed and there is a script called `weyland-config.js`. I'm not sure if these are the cause of the problem though.

If I use two machines (with the same versions of VS, both on Windows 11) and both with the same codebase, one machine builds to `~/build` while the other goes to `~/bin/build`. On the first machine, the build works fine but on the other, I get an error that the `weyland-config.js` file is missing. When I look at the build tab, they are both directing to `bin\`

They are using the following post build script (useful for showing everything worked fine)

```
        echo ------ Post-build event Start - $(ConfigurationName) ------

        cd $(ProjectDir)

        if '$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release' (

        attrib -R App\main-built.js
        weyland build

        cd $(ProjectDir)\_Deployment_Files
        Deploy_SPA_Files "$(ConfigurationName)" "$(SolutionName)" "$(ProjectName)" "$(ProjectDir)"

        echo ------ Post-build event End - $(ConfigurationName) ------
        )
        if '$(ConfigurationName)'=='Debug' (

        ECHO Remove built js files to cleanup debug process
        REM DEL /F /Q /S "App\*built.js"

        echo ------ Post-build event End - $(ConfigurationName) ------
        )
```

This is never hit on machine 2, but is always hit on machine 1.